# Closing the application/stopping timers vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, timer

I have this `Sub` running on a timer in my application. I want to terminate the program after 3 consecutive failed connection to the server. I've tried placing `Application.Exit` right after the `MsgBox` but it doesn't solve my problem. The timer still runs after the `MsgBox` has shown and I think the `Application.Exit` is not executing.

```
Public Sub Reader(ByVal strsql As String)
    Try
        cm = New MySqlCommand(strsql, con)
        openConnection()
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader()
    Catch ex As Exception
        errorCounter += 1
        If errorCounter = 3 Then
            MsgBox("Server is down. Application now exiting...", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Server down.")
            'exit the application.
        Else
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any solution for this? or a better idea, I guess. Thank You!

Comment: Try/Catch is not for controlling code execution; `Application.Exit` doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: @Plutonix so, how am I suppose to handle this problem?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads or backgroundworkers in this app?

Comment: Anyway its not the best structured code as plutonix suggests, but I created a new app, added a timer and plugged in this code and the `Application.Exit` closes the app fine. Since it doesn't work for you I am assuming you have some kind of complex objects still open in your app and/or multiple threads which are still open and therefore your app is not closing properly. We really need to know more about your app to help you because although the code you posted could be better, it works as expected by itself.

Comment: Please bare with me, I'm new to programming. I tried stopping the timers and the application did close but it took sometime. I have no idea if I have multiple threads running in my app. What I am using are just timers.

Comment: If thats the case then I would recommend stopping the timer before you show your messagebox (also you should use `Messagebox.Show` instead of `MsgBox` since it's the proper .Net way to do it - `MsgBox` is the old old old way to do it) and then start it again after the `ex.Message` message. Do not start the timer again after the `Server is down` message since you don't want the timer running anymore if you are going to close the app. Also, you mentioned timer(s) so if you have any other timers running when you close the app I would recommend stopping those before you close it all down.

Answer (score 2):

Timers can be tricky and hard to debug, especially if the interval is very short.  In your example, I would try something like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  Timer1.Enabled = False
  call sub...
End Sub

Public Sub Reader(ByVal strsql As String)
   Try
     code...
   Catch ex As Exception
     errorCounter += 1
     If errorCounter = 3 Then
        MsgBox("Server is down. Application now exiting...", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Server down.")
     Else
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Timer1.enabled=True
     End If
   End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
If errorCounter = 3 Then
  Timer1.stop()
  MsgBox("Server is down. Application now exiting...", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Server down.")
  End
Else
  MsgBox(ex.Message)
End If
```

Stop the timer if the counter reaches 3 (based on your requirement). The reason why the program is still running is you did not stop the timer. I think the End function will do the trick in closing the application.

**EDIT**
Also, don't put the code on the Catch. Create a code that checks if the user have failed connection instead of putting on the Catch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first stop the Timer when the count reach 3 then display the message and then exit the application as @JStevens has stated. The End will do the trick, also if you have another form like you have 2 forms and the second form is that tries to connect ensure you call

```
  Application.Exit()
  ' Just to force the app to exit add another closing call
 Close()
```

But the Application exit call will close all running forms, you need to stop all the timers you have before closing.